# .NET 6 Web Api Project No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have a simple javascript app calling a .NET 6 Web API

In the program.cs file, I have added builder.Services.AddCors and app.UseCors as below.

But I still get CORS error when making a POST Request:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.2.157:81/Controller/MyMethod' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My CORS config:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "AllowAll",
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
                          policy.AllowAnyMethod();
                          policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                      });
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseCors("AllowAll");
//app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I've also tried to enable it inside the appsetting (Both for the default and development file):

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "cors": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "origin": "*",
        "allow": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any idea why i'm not able to enable the CORS policy?

i'm publishing in a docker container and everything works if i run it locally, if it's of any help

Comment: When adding the CORS config in Program.cs, your api has enabled cors policy, just like what you said you can call api succsessfully locally, so I'm afraid the issue is related to docker.

Comment: so maybe [this one](https://docs.browserless.io/docs/docker.html#enable-cors) you may try..

Comment: @TinyWang It seems to work. 

I added "<DockerfileRunArguments>-e "ENABLE_CORS=true" -p 81:80</DockerfileRunArguments>" inside <PropertyGroup> of my .csproj and now i'm able to call my web server (http://192.168.2.157:81/) form my client (127.0.0.1)

Thank you so much! You save my week ;-)

Comment: You can post what you did and mark it as he answer to end this case : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TinyWang :

I added

```
<DockerfileRunArguments>-e "ENABLE_CORS=true" -p 81:80</DockerfileRunArguments>
```

inside  of my .csproj.

Now i'm able to call my web server (192.168.2.157:81) form my client (127.0.0.1)